# How did this question get so many views so fast?

Tags: support, questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371292/buffered-reading-from-stdin-using-fread-in-c) question just came into SO and after 23 secs had about 226 views.  What's going on?

Comment: Check your default question sort order to be sure you're on "newest" instead of "hot" or "active".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was asked two days ago, it was edited a couple of minutes before you made this question. ~250 views seems to be normal.